# tfs 2015 build not performing nuget package restore

Tags: tfs, build, build-process, tfs-2015, nuget-package-restore

I have a bit of a strange situation.  2 applications in the same tfs repository, both using near identical build definitions, both using nuget packages, one performs a package restore, one does not.

Both build definitions contain the 'Restore NuGet Packages' option checked:

[image]

both have same .sln and .vbproj file structures.

build log of the 'good' one gives:

[image]

and the 'bad' one doesnt:

[image]

Build controller/agent is the same, I cant see any difference in the build definition or the solution configuration.

My question is where do I start looking for why these are doing something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the packages.config files for each of the projects were not checked in to TFS, without these there was nothing to restore.  Stupid error!